# how to insert simple gmaps in a block

Tags: google-maps

How can I insert a simple google map in a block?

I have a contact page with a contact-form (that one can fill in and send),
and I want to add to this page a google map.

thanks alot in advance!

Comment: Hello. Have you tried to Google it and use search on Drupal.org? There are modules to do things like that, aren't they? There is even one simply called GMap Module.

Comment: Go through this article, Hope this will help http://webwash.net/tutorials/how-display-maps-using-gmap-views-and-location-drupal-7

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways you can do this.

1. Go to maps.google.com, type in the address, get the link, then click the customize and preview embedded view. A popup should appear. Select the map size you want. Copy the html code and go to structure -> blocks -> add block, paste your code and select full html filter. And add your block to where you want it
2. Download the [gmaps module](https://drupal.org/project/gmap) and use it. By default is has a block created called location map

> The GMap module provides an interface to the Google Maps API within
>   Drupal. It integrates with the Location module to provide users a
>   clickable map for entering latitude and longitude, as well as to
>   display maps of Drupal nodes and users. GMap can be used to create
>   interactive maps with various map markers and content in map bubbles,
>   taking advantage of Drupal's other content management features. The
>   module also provides a Views display plugin which allows users to
>   display the results of a view on a Google map.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply!                                              I tried number 1 and it shows me the html code on the website.  (number 2 I thought maybe its stupid to add a module for one map, is it true,)

Comment: I would go with number 1 since that's your only need for maps. Did you change your filter to full html.

Comment: yes i changed my filter to full html

Comment: Do you have wysiwyg on the body field of your block?

Comment: yes I think so because I can add pictures and change font...

Comment: At the bottom of the field, click on disable rich text before pasting the code

Comment: thanks, I did it and I saw the map but after 1 second it disapears and u see only a link:  View Larger Map

Comment: have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the previous answer above;
There has been some changes to the Google maps GUI, thus in other to access the "embed link" option, you will have to navigate as follows;

1. Click the little gear option to the right had corner of the screen[image]
2. Then you will see the option "share and embed maps" option [image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this with a block, but I have an iframe field attached to my basic page. Then adding the Google Maps API is easy with this doc: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide. Copy the line with your API key `https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA` to the Iframe URL, and it should work!